# How come assigning to a register is not causing problems with everything else?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

In Assembly, we commonly use instructions like `mov` and `ld` and others to load values into registers. However, why does it just work? For example, if a program is writing a value into the `eax` register, and another program reads from that, why doesn't it read the value the other program wrote? Does the CPU or OS or something like that provide a set of registers for each running program maybe?

Comment: See also [time slice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice).  Handling out time slices of the CPU is an operating system feature that virtualizes the compute power of the CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the CPU or OS or something like that provide a set of registers for each running program maybe?

Yes. Each process, or each thread, or each task, has its own register set. When the OS preempts a task it saves all registers in a task-specific memory area. Then to resume the same task or another task, the target task's register values are restored from that task's memory area.